# Android Tablelayout problem!

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have a TableLayout in which I have one row holding two TextViews, the first one holds a String representation of a Date, the second one holds a title. My problem is the first one should always be 100dp wide, the seconde one should use the spaces that's left. The first TextView works fine and it will go to a new line if the string cannot be displayed in one line. But the problem is the second TextView, it is always too wide (its width expands out of the screen), no matter how I change its size, and I can only see part of the text that's inside it. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txtView1 = new TextView(this);
LinearLayout lLay= new LinarLayout(this);
txtView2 = new TextView(this);
lLay.addView(txtView2);
row.addview(txtView1);
row.addview(lLay,220,Layout.Wrap_Content);
```

just try this coz it solve my problem.